# How disable copy and paste windows server 2008

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I need create Group policy to use disable copy and paste  windows server 2008 please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  While it is possible to disable copy/paste in certain applications like Internet Explorer, there are workarounds.  System wide, it simply impossible.

Comment: Are there specific programs doing this